# MySQL - Uploading Image To BLOB Max Upload Size?

Tags: php, mysql, blob

I'm using file uploading for images into a BLOB in a MySQL  database, for some reason when I upload some pictures I noticed they weren't completely rendered, I then tried uploading directly into PHPMyAdmin when it then showed  `(Max: 64KiB)` I luckily enough run my own server so I thought to go check my php.ini for max file upload size, it's set to 250MB. So my question is,

**Where is the max filesize for MySQL BLOB Uploads??**

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It depends on the type of your column.

From [MySQL documentation:](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html), section *Storage Requirements for String Types*:

> #### TINYBLOB
>
> L+1 bytes, where L < 2<sup>8</sup>  **(256 bytes)**
>
> #### BLOB
>
> L+2 bytes, where L < 2<sup>16</sup>  **(65 kilobytes)**
>
> #### MEDIUMBLOB
>
> L+3 bytes, where L < 2<sup>24</sup>   **(16 megabytes)**
>
> #### LONGBLOB
>
> L+4 bytes, where L < 2<sup>32</sup>   **(4 gigabytes)**

Comment: Ah wow I didn't even realize that the type was the issue. I thank you good sir :)

Comment: @Ariana You're welcome! Don't forget to adapt your maximum upload size accordingly though ;)

Comment: I'm using blob to keep images, but Mediumblob is large type data, there isn't a Blob with 8 or 4 megabytes. Or if I use mediumblob and save an image of 4MB, others 12MB it lose?

Comment: @CampDev You can store up to 16MB : the space isn't allocated until you store something, you won't have 12MB locked and lost if you save a 4MB pic.