# How to upload 2+ MB file into xampp MySQL via phplocalmyadmin?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, xampp

I'm creating a database and was trying to upload my images into it. However, I encounter a sql server run away error when i tried to upload a 2+MB file.

When I upload a 4MB file, the page simply resets

When i upload a 30+kb file, it works !

I have created the column (longblob) and change the upload_max_file size limit in php.ini to 64MB.

[image: The error is shown in this picture]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to consider more things to do this job.

1. 'max_allowed_packet'

   mysql> show variables like 'max_allowed_packet';
2. Your Column type. [MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html)

   TINYBLOB

   L+1 bytes, where L < 28 ± 256 bytes
   BLOB

   L+2 bytes, where L < 216 ± 65 kilobytes
   MEDIUMBLOB

   L+3 bytes, where L < 224 ± 16 megabytes
   LONGBLOB

   L+4 bytes, where L < 232 ± 4 gigabytes
3. The better and faster way is store/upload your image/file into disk storage, not db storage. And just store the file location into db.

And read these link:
[How can I insert large files in MySQL db using PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492549/how-can-i-insert-large-files-in-mysql-db-using-php)

[MySQL - Uploading Image To BLOB Max Upload Size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19943529/mysql-uploading-image-to-blob-max-upload-size)