# Upload Image using Php and mySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to upload image using php and save in mysql database that would accept the different extension of it such as bmp, jpeg etc. By using the following codes, some of the uploaded images displayed incomplete.

This is the uploadForm:

```
<html>
  <form method="post" action="updateImage1.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <table border=0>
  <tr>
    <td><center><img src="getImage.php?id='.$row["No"].'" width=250 height=180/></center><br>      
    <input type="file" name="s4"><br>
    <input name="update" type="submit" id="update" value="Save Changes" class="btn btn-primary" >
    &nbsp &nbsp
     </form><a href="admin3.php"><button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Cancel</button></a>
 </tr>

 </table>
 </html>
```

This is the updateImage1.php:

```
<?php
$s1 = addslashes(file_get_contents($_FILES['s4']['tmp_name']));

$host="localhost";
$user_name="root";
$database_name="5r";
$db=mysql_connect($host, $user_name,'');
if (mysql_error() > "") echo mysql_error() . "<br>";
mysql_select_db($database_name, $db);
if (mysql_error() > "") echo mysql_error() . "<br>";

$query = "UPDATE tblMain SET images='$s1' WHERE No=3";
$qresult = mysql_query($query);
echo "<script>alert('Records Successfully Updated'); location.href='admin3.php';</script>";
?>
```

This is the getImage.php:

```
 <?php

 $No = $_GET['id'];
 $link = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
 mysql_select_db("5r");
 $sql = "SELECT images FROM tblMain WHERE No=$No";
 $result = mysql_query("$sql");
 $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
 mysql_close($link);

 header("Content-type: image/jpeg/bmp/png");
 echo $row['images'];
 ?>
```

Comment: 1) Where is the insert inside db? 2) mysql_* is deprecated, 3) how big of image are we talking about?

Comment: I doubt this is valid `header("Content-type: image/jpeg/bmp/png");` as per the manual http://php.net/manual/en/function.image-type-to-mime-type.php - I suggest you look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/2634072/

Comment: I did not used the Insert statement, because I'm trying to update the uploaded image on database. But every time I uploaded an image that has been edited in picasa photo viewer and has an extension of bmp, the image displayed incomplete.

Comment: You're welcome Rachelle.

Comment: What is the database type of `images`

Comment: @David -- I used Blob type. Why?

Comment: Do the images become complete if using a Medium or Long Blob?

Comment: I never try that medium or long blob eh. What is the difference among them? I'll try to use those data type. Thanks David. :)

Comment: Check out [this answer to SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19943593/974781).

Comment: **mysql** (plain) has been deprecated and will someday disappear. [This page shows it's replacements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php). **mysqli** is not too different, mostly improved.

Comment: Okey David, thanks for the help. ^__^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the data type of the **images** into **Long Blob**.